# Trigger my app when Pushover app receives notification

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Most of you know Pushover app. So what I want is when the pushover app receives message or notification, my app will be triggered. That's all in Android.

So Can any one help me to find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Spontit can do this.

Spontit is somewhat similar to Pushover, but is free, you can have unlimited followers, and enable unlimited devices, plus a few more things. ([web-app](https://spontit.com/), [API](https://api.spontit.com/))

To get started with what you want to do, check out [Spontit on IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/spontit). Spontit has a trigger for when a notification is sent.

Both Pushover and Spontit offer an *action* on IFTTT (send a push notification), but only Spontit offers a trigger (push was sent), which might help you. Feel free to add more details about your use case.